# Installing Themes to open EDX

Tags: 20.04, permissions, themes

I'm new to Ubuntu and using 20.04 and trying to configure my open EDX, I'm trying to set my theme up and I'm unable to edit the files within the `edx` directory due to not having permissions.

The current permissions say that it is owned by `edxapp` and I can't change this due to having no permission.

In the guides I am following says to edit a file so that the theme can work, only problem is I keep getting `Permission Denied, Error code 3`. So I am unsure.

Has anyone encountered this problem and, if so, how do I fix this and give myself permissions?

Comment: I do not know EDX are you supposed to be able to edit them or just something you want to do?

Comment: In the guides I am following says to edit a file so that the theme can work, only problem is I keep getting Permission Denied, Error code 3. So i am unsure.

Comment: If permission is denied, have you tried running command as sudo?